# POST to same page security; empty vs htmlentities

Tags: php

I am looking for the correct and most secure method of POSTing to the same page without directly defining the page itself. For example not using

```
<form method="post" action="/mypage.php">
```

Despite this being a fairly basic usage of PHP, I have found multiple contradictory sources giving advice on how to do this. Currently I simply use

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

With some source suggesting (incorrectly?)

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

However after reading more into this, [one](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html) recommendation suggests using `htmlentities()`

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
```

I believe this is the most correct method for sanitisation against xss exploits, but was curious is this needed if `action=""`

Comment: If you use `action=""` and url changed on client side (#hash or `history.push()`), form will posted to new url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With modern HTML, just omit the `action` attribute entirely. HTML 5 defines that the form should then submit to the current URL. This is the simplest and least error prone option.

When you do echo user input (such as the URL) back to the browser, always use appropriate escaping for the document type you are putting it in (`htmlspecialchars` for HTML, `json_encode` for JavaScript, etc) to protect yourself from XSS.

`action` is an HTML attribute so it has no intrinsic defence against XSS.

`PHP_SELF` is:

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.

So, unless you have put characters with special meaning in HTML into one of your file or directory names, it *should* be safe to echo out without escaping. However: It does no harm to play it safe and treat it like any other text you want to convert to HTML and use `htmlspecialchars` with it. So play it safe.